# How to configure Chartjs Bar Stacked Chart in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, chart.js

I want to make a bar stacked graph with 2 datasets with Chartjs 6 -  Laravel 8

```
 $chart->labels($resultados1);
 $chart->dataset('Dataset1','bar',$resultados2)->backgroundColor(collect(['#7158e2']));
 $chart->dataset('Dataset2','bar',$resultados3)->backgroundColor(collect(['#1158e2']));
//>>>>>>>>$chart->scales('xAxes','stacked' => true , 'yAxes' => ['stacked' => true]);<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
But obviously this last commented line is wrong
```

I've found how to make this by javascript but I need to put this on laravel code easily
The only thing I need to do is configure the chart axes as "stacked ->true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$chartOptions = [
    'scales' => [
        'yAxes' => [
            
                'stacked' => true,
            ],
            'xAxes' => 
                [
                    'stacked' => true,
                ],
        ],
    
];


 $chart->labels($resultados1);
 $chart->options($chartOptions);
```